# R- Not Loading all 5 variables only 1

Tags: r

Last night I attended my 1st R class and I am having some difficulties using  the read.csv function. When I tried to run the function it is only uploading the 1st variable.
Does anyone know why this is happening. I don't know if it makes a difference but I am using a Mac.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Your CSV as well, please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but sometimes when I create a .csv file from an excel file all of the variables collapse into one variable (I don't know why). Check the structure of your dataset using head(df) or str(df) (where df is the name of your data) and confirm that this didn't happen. If it did happen, you'll have to fix the .csv. If that isn't the problem, I'm not sure what the issue is.

For future reference it would help for you to supply a reproducible sample of your data as well as the full script that you are using.

Comment: Thank you !! For future inquiries I will provide samples.

Comment: @LucianaSantos no need to wait for the future—you can edit the question to include your example